# New to Java & Series

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, series

I'm brand new to Java & series (summing up no.s in a certain way using Java).

The user needs to input n (a positive even integer). This can be 0, 2, 4, and any increment of 2 above.

If I put in 4, Java must calculate 2 + 4 = 6. If I put in 6, Java must calculate 2 + 4 + 6 = 12. Java needs to sum numbers as follows for an input n... 2 + 4 + 6 + ... + n = some sum. I wanted to see how this can be done by a loop. The following was an attempt of mine. We just assume the user will put in a positive even integer like 2, 4, 6, 8, or 10 & so on (so we don't have to test for that).

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0, n;
System.out.println("Give me a positive even integer.");
n = console.nextInt();

while (sum < n) {
    sum = sum + 2;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Again, the point is to sum from 2 up until the positive even number given by the user.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Clarified. It shouldn't be on hold now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop condition `(sum < n)` is incorrect since `sum` will very soon be greater than the final term value `n`.

**But**, You can do this without a loop:

```
sum = n / 2 * (2 + (n / 2 - 1))
```

Where `n` is even and positive as you describe. This comes from the formula for an *arithmetic progression* sum.

If you *really* want to use a `for` loop then use

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2){
    sum += i;
}
```

or, if you want a `while` then use

```
int sum = 0;
{ /*extra scoping block so we don't emit i*/
    int i = 0;
    while ((i += 2) <= n){
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

noting that `(i += 2)` is an *expression* evaluated to the incremented value of `i`.

Comment: Do you know how to do this strictly using a loop? I'm looking to do this using a loop only.

Comment: @LisaSmith: added, but note that it is not as efficient as using the analytic result.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. I've at least done series before, but I'm required to do a loop. If I could ask one more thing out of curiosity... how would you do this using a while loop?

Comment: @LisaSmith: I've added a `while` case.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    System.out.println("Give me a positive even integer.");
    int n = console.nextInt() / 2;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) sum += 2 * i;
    System.out.println(sum);
} finally { console.close(); }
```

Besides: it handles odd numbers as well and releases the console, which is a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code adds always 2 to the sum. However, you want to add numbers that are increased by 2. So basically, you need another variable counting the current element in the series 2, 4, 6 you are at.

```
int index = 2;
while( index <= n ) {
    sum = sum + index;
    index = index + 2;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, right? I put in 10 & it gave me 20. The answer should be 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 30, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The last n was not counted. The condition should be index <= n. I chose this solution because it is nearest to your own.